# Как убрать slider в combobox CSS javaFX?

Tags: css, javafx

Пишу приложение на JavaFx, проблема заключается в том, что при большом количестве элементов в Combobox появляется slider, который хотелось бы скрыть, но оставив функционал сдвига, так сказать. Как такое можно реализовать?

Пытался использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
.combo-box .thumb {
-fx-opacity: 0;}
```

[image: Проблема]

Comment: Подключите к проекту https://github.com/JonathanGiles/scenic-view оно точно покажет какие стили есть у элемента, что бы их переопределить у себя. При подключении могут понадобиться маты и крепкие напитки.